# unable to use an intersection type when notional class requires access modification

Tags: java, javac

Interfaces:

```
interface PublicCloneable {
    Object clone();
}

interface HasPosition {
    // doesn't matter
}
```

Attempt to use intersection type:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
<E extends PublicCloneable & HasPosition> E cloneAndIncrementPosition(E elem) {
    final E clone = (E)elem.clone();
    // rest omitted
}
```

Attempt to compile with `javac 1.8.0_60`:

```
$ javac xx.java
xx.java:13: error: clone() in Object cannot implement clone() in PublicCloneable
    <E extends PublicCloneable & HasPosition> E cloneAndIncrementPosition(E elem) {
     ^
  attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public
xx.java:14: error: clone() has protected access in Object
        final E clone = (E)elem.clone();
                               ^
2 errors
```

Why this intersection type is invalid for javac?

Comment: Interestingly, if you remove the upper bound `HasPosition` from `E`, then this compiles.

Comment: This compiles on Eclipse...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This looks like a javac bug.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4

> The members of a type variable X with bound T & I1 & ... & In are the members of the intersection type (§4.9) T & I1 & ... & In

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.9

> Every intersection type T1 & ... & Tn induces a notional class or interface for the purpose of identifying the members of the intersection type ...
>
> If Ck is Object, a notional interface is induced ...  has direct superinterfaces T1', ..., Tn'

Therefore, for `PublicCloneable & HasPosition`, a notional interface is introduced, extending both of them, which should be OK.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was suspecting. Glad you agree.

Comment: Well, this part of the spec is badly written, and it's not coherent under closer look. In any case, your use case looks perfectly legit and it ought to be accepted.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! Any ways to suppress this error and compile such code?

Answer (score 0):

As the first error is trying to tell you, your code cannot work, because you're constraining to types with two incompatible signatures for the `clone()` method.

Comment: E.g., `HasPosition`'s `clone` (inherited from `Object`) is `protected`, but `PublicCloneable`s `clone`, since it's an interface, is `public`. Is that right?