# Generics issue: clone() attempting to assign weaker access privileges

Tags: java, generics, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, clone

Let's have this class structure:

```
public interface TypeIdentifiable {}

public interface TypeCloneable extends Cloneable {
  public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException;
}

public class Foo implements TypeCloneable, TypeIdentifiable {

   @Override
   public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
      // ...
      return null;
   }
}

public abstract class AbstractClass<T extends TypeCloneable & TypeIdentifiable> {

   public void foo(T element) throws Exception {
      TypeCloneable cloned = (TypeCloneable) element.clone();
      System.out.println(cloned);
   }
}
```

I have this compilation error (although the IDE, Intellij in my case, is unable to show the error while coding)

```
Error:(4, 37) java: clone() in java.lang.Object cannot implement clone() in foo.TypeCloneable attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public
```

I know that the compiler is trying to call `clone()` method from `Object` instead of `TypeCloneable`, but I don't understand why. I also tried it casting to `TypeCloneable` (I suposed the compiler would know which `clone()` method call in this case, but the same problem).

```
   public void foo(T element) throws Exception {
      TypeCloneable typeCloneable = (TypeCloneable) element;
      TypeCloneable cloned = (TypeCloneable) typeCloneable.clone();
   }
```

I'm a bit confused...Can I do something here to force callling clone() from TypeCloneable?

Thanks for the hellp

Comment: If I understand the JLS correctly, this should compile. I think it's a bug. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33023332/why-doesnt-this-java-program-compile

Comment: So yes...it seems to be a bug. I didn't found this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me, (I am guessing it is a problem with the Type & Type upperbound syntax):

```
interface TypeIdentifiable {}

interface TypeCloneable extends Cloneable {
  public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException;
}

class Foo implements TypeCloneable, TypeIdentifiable {

   @Override
   public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
      // ...
      return null;
   }
}

interface TypeCloneableAndIndetifiable extends TypeCloneable, TypeIdentifiable  {

}
abstract class AbstractClass<T extends TypeCloneableAndIndetifiable> {

   public void foo(T element) throws Exception {
      TypeCloneable cloned = (TypeCloneable) element.clone();
      System.out.println(cloned);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering @WillShackleford. Yes, if I wrap both interfaces into one, as you say, it works. The problem is that both TypeCloneable and TypeIdentifiable are legacy code. Do you think this could be a bug with the & Type upperbound syntax?

Comment: I am not certain. I would have thought it would worked as you used it before I saw this question.

Comment: As @Paul Boddington points in a comment, it seems to be a bug. Maybe you could edit your answer adding this. Anyway, I accept your aswer for your suggestion about wrapping two interfaces into one. Thanks